# Apache Airflow kubernetes pod operator how do we pass configMap value in `value_from` while forming the environment variable in DAG

Tags: environment-variables, kubernetes-pod, airflow

I am using Apache Airflow where in one of our DAG's task we are using Kubernetes Pod Operator. This is being done to execute one of our application process in a kubernetes pod. The Kubernetes pod operator works all good.Passing environmental variables via the pod operator works all good. However I am trying to pass an environment variable value from a Kubernetes ConfigMap it is not able to get the values from ConfigMap.

Code snippet is as below. In the code snippet please focus on the line `'SPARK_CONFIG': '{"valueFrom": {"configMapKeyRef": {"key": "endpoint","name": "spark-config"}}}'`

Please find below the code snippet

```
pod_process_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace=cons.K8_NAMESPACE,
        image=cons.UNCOMPRESS_IMAGE_NAME,
        config_file=cons.K8_CONFIG_FILE,
        env_vars={
            'FRT_ID': '{{ dag_run.conf["transaction_id"] }}',
            'FILE_NAME': '{{ dag_run.conf["filename"]}}',
            'FILE_PATH': '{{dag_run.conf["filepath"]}}' + "/" + '{{ dag_run.conf["filename"]}}',
            'LOG_FILE': '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="process_log_dict")["loglocation"] }}',
            'SPARK_CONFIG': '{"valueFrom": {"configMapKeyRef": {"key": "endpoint","name": "spark-config"}}}'
        },
        name=create_pod_name(),
        # name= 'integrator',
        task_id="decrypt-951",
        retries=3,
        retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=60),
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        volumes=[volume-a,volume_for_configuration],
        volume_mounts=[volume_mount_a,volume_mount_config],
        resources=pod_resource_specification,
        startup_timeout_seconds=cons.K8_POD_TIMEOUT,
        get_logs=True,
        on_failure_callback=log_failure_unzip_decrypt,
        dag=dag
    )
```

Then on trying to print the variable from the pod I am getting as below. Please note that the other ENV_VARIABLE values have been populated except for the one where I am trying to reference the configMap. Please find below the log output that we get to see while the K8-Pod is being spawned. [In the snippet below , please focus on the parameter `'name': 'SPARK_CONFIG'` ]. The rest of the env_variables seems to have the value populated as what I have provided in the code snippet above with Jinga-templating.

```
'containers': [{'args': None,
                          'command': None,
                          'env': [{'name': 'FRT_ID',
                                   'value': '20180902_01605',
                                   'value_from': None},
                                  {'name': 'FILE_NAME',
                                   'value': 'transact_2018-09-02_0321_file_MAR.zip',
                                   'value_from': None},
                                  {'name': 'FILE_PATH',
                                   'value': '/etc/data/app/trk0057.zip',
                                   'value_from': None},                                  
                                  {'name': 'LOG_FILE',
                                   'value': 'log-0057_2018-09.log',
                                   'value_from': None},
                                  {'name': 'SPARK_CONFIG',
                                   'value': '{"valueFrom": {"configMapKeyRef": '
                                            '{"key": "endpoint","name": '
                                            '"spark-config"}}}',
                                   'value_from': None}],
                          'env_from': None

...
...
...
...
```

The point is as to how do we pass the ConfigMap value as with the `value_from` while forming the environment variable in the Apache Airflow kubernetes pod operator

Comment: @Grant T : Would appreciate by any chance can you come to any assistance on this query.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the KubernetesPodOperator `configmaps` parameter. You can see the docstring here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py#L104

So in this way you would pass `configmaps=["spark-config"]` presuming your configmap is named `spark-config`.

Comment: @chris.mclennon : Thank You so much Chris. 
I am using Airflow 1.10.2 , so wondering from which version this has been factored. Just in case you know.

Comment: [OhHiMark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11560878/ohhimark) / @OhHiMark   : It though seems informative but the fact that I am using Airflow 1.10.2 version ... this doesn't seem to help. The version I am using, there the KubernetesPodOperator has basic support for Secret and Configmap, mostly by mounting them in files or mounting specific keys in environment variables.
Its more by just mounting environment variables directly through whole k8s Configmap or Secret to a volume mount location while you create the K8PodOperator in the DAG.

Comment: @Shanit Based on reading the Airflow changelog, it does look like configmap was added in 1.10.3, so unfortunately it's not available to you in 1.10.2 until you do an update

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/changelog.html#airflow-1-10-3-2019-04-09

Comment: @chris.mclennon : Thank You so much for your response and information.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I added configmaps with the name of the configmap, but the env_var still does not parse correctly (exactly like in the example in the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Airflow Version: v2.3.3

```
task_in_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(
  ...
  
  env_vars={
    "VAR_NAME1": "STRING_VALUE1",
    "VAR_NAME2": "STRING_VALUE2",
    "NEW_VAR_NAME": "$(VAR_NAME_FROM_CONFIG_MAP)" # <- value from ConfigMap
  },
  configmaps=['configmap-name'], # <- assume this one is already exists

  ...
)
```