# In Airflow, how do we pass environment variables to Kubernetes Executor worker pods?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow `1.0.15`. It is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster using the Airflow official helm charts. And i'm not able to pass an environment variable to the worker pods.

The `extraEnv` added in the helm chart were added to the scheduler and web pods but not the worker pods which use Kubernetes Executor.

I was able to mount a configmap into the worker pod using the `executor_config` parameter. But how do we pass an environment variable to a worker pod?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem trying to pass environment variables to the KubernetesExecutor pods using this [airflow-helm community chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow).

After a few dead ends trying to set variables via config map and as per [airflow variables doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) and [airflow config doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html) e.g.:

```
airflow:
  config:
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL: "30"
    my_env_var: "hello this is your env var"
    AIRFLOW__my_env_var: "hello this is your env var"
    AIRFLOW__VAR__my_env_var: "hello this is your env var"
```

I found that setting environment varibales within the below `extraEnv:` block in helm values.yaml works [following the documentation in the faq](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-environment-variables.md). Setting `extaEnv` results in values mapping from  [helper pods.tpl](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/templates/_helpers/pods.tpl#L582-L586) into the [k8 pod template file](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/files/pod_template.kubernetes-helm-yaml).

```
airflow:
  extraEnv:
    - name: my_env_var
      value: "hello this is your env var"
    - name: my_other_env_var
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: my-kubectl-secret
          key: value
```

In my case, I create secrets with kubectl or substitute in the values as part of the deployment pipeline. The downside is that my helm chart needs to be updated for each new secret / environment variables.

Lastly, these are **not** set as Airflow variables. They are standard environment variables on kubernetes pod os. In your DAGs and tasks you access them e.g.

```
def task():
    import os
    var = os.getenv('my_env_var')
    return {
        'message': var
    }
```

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61816701/4538066) suggests another method using config-maps.